# SQL multiply and round in select statement

Tags: select, decimal, rounding, sql-function, multiplication

In part of my select statement, I want to round the value to two decimals. The select has a multiplication where I take one column's value and multiply it by another and divide by 100. I want this value to be returned with only two decimal places but nothing seems to be working right. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
 SELECT
     a.Rate AS 'Rate'
     ,a.LoI AS 'Liability'
 ---------------------------------------------------
 ---- Tried Each Of These Seperately ---------------
 ---------------------------------------------------

     CAST(a.Rate * a.LoI / 100, money) AS 'Premium'

     ROUND(a.Rate * a.LoI / 100,2) AS 'Premium'

     CAST((A.Rate * a.LoI / 100), money) AS 'Premium'

     CONVERT(A.Rate * a.LoI / 100, money) AS 'Premium'

FROM tblAspecs a
```

a.Rate is a of data type `Decimal(10,2)`

a.LoI is of data type `bigint`

I'm Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

select cast((123.456 * 2 / 100) as decimal(38,2))

works for me :) But that maybe wasn't what you wanted?

So I guess you could try:

```
SELECT
 a.Rate AS 'Rate'
 ,a.LoI AS 'Liability'
 ,CAST((a.Rate * a.LoI / 100) AS decimal(38,2)) 'Premium' FROM tblAspecs a
```

Comment: That worked. Looks like I used the CAST syntax incorrectly since I didn't have the 'AS' declaration in there and also didn't have the decimal datatype setup properly.

Thanks @KTrum